# Adding a nested map for React code in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have tried to modify this code in my Gatsby project and add a nested map to render the contents of the JSON file.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function getJson() {
  return fetch('http://secstat.info/testthechartdata3.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}

const MyComp = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getJson().then(list => setList(list));
  }, []);

  return (
    <ul>
      {list.map(item => (
        <li key={item.id}>{item.count}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

When I add `list[0].map` to the code above I can see my data but I am unable to get a nested map working.

How do I print the `item.id` and `item.count` for all of the data in this JSON file please?  I think it should look something like this but I can't get it to work.  Appreciate any help with this.

```
list.map(nestedjson=>
nestedjson.map(item => (
            <li key={item.id}>{item.count}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
```

This is the data structure.

[image: data structure2]

Expanded to show key value.

[image: data structure]

Comment: show data structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think of the each nested array as a container, you iterate over those first, and then iterate over the array of objects it contains. In this example I've added some extra `<ul>` and `<li>` to help visualise this.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const data = [[{"id": "ransomware", "count": 409}, {"id": "phishing", "count": 358}, {"id": "apt", "count": 296}, {"id": "trojans", "count": 180}, {"id": "viruses", "count": 111}, {"id": "backdoors", "count": 99}, {"id": "dos", "count": 97}, {"id": "social engineering", "count": 72}, {"id": "insider threat", "count": 71}, {"id": "payloads", "count": 65}], [{"id": "cve-2019-19781", "count": 15}, {"id": "cve-2019-0708", "count": 14}, {"id": "cve-2020-0601", "count": 9}, {"id": "cve-2020-0674", "count": 8}, {"id": "cve-2019-1182", "count": 8}, {"id": "cve-2019-1181", "count": 8}, {"id": "cve-2019-11510", "count": 7}, {"id": "cve-2019-1367", "count": 7}, {"id": "cve-2020-0796", "count": 6}, {"id": "cve-2019-1429", "count": 6}], [{"id": "banking", "count": 171}, {"id": "retail", "count": 73}, {"id": "military", "count": 67}, {"id": "education", "count": 44}, {"id": "insurance", "count": 38}, {"id": "energy", "count": 36}, {"id": "transport", "count": 29}, {"id": "health care", "count": 29}, {"id": "finance", "count": 22}, {"id": "telcos", "count": 21}], [{"id": "emotet", "count": 61}, {"id": "trickbot", "count": 51}, {"id": "ryuk", "count": 41}, {"id": "bluekeep", "count": 40}, {"id": "wannacry", "count": 35}, {"id": "rover", "count": 18}, {"id": "dridex", "count": 15}, {"id": "azorult", "count": 13}, {"id": "epic", "count": 12}, {"id": "wiper", "count": 11}]];

function MyComp() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => setList(data), []);

  return (
    <ul>
      {list.map(container => (
        <li className="container"><ul>
          {container.map(item => (
            <li key={item.id}>{item.count}</li>
          ))}
        </ul></li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComp />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Note that I only put the data in the answer for convenience. You should continue to use the API like in your question. @ade1e

Answer (score -1):

Yes Your Approach would work !!

```
return (
    <ul>
      {list.map(nest => {
        return nest.map(item => 
        <li key={item.id}>{item.count}</li>
       )
      })
     }
    </ul>
  );
```

Some syntax issues I have fixed check once !!

Comment: have you seen the data of json ?

Comment: also you are not returning nest.map, this code will never work.

Comment: @ade1e
 try this

Comment: you remove state since you are using hooks